# How to select and share multiple files in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I've seen capacitor share plugin, but as I understood, you can only share one file at a time with it. Am I wrong or can I share multiple files at once with it? Additionally, is there another way to achieve this (maybe with another plugin or something)?

Comment: `https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#you-can-still-use-the-older-share-method-as-well` as said it in this section, u can share multiple files as third param

Comment: @MostafaHarb have you used this plugin? I've tried it, but everytime I try to share a file I get some message that the files couldn't be attached (in Gmail I get 'Unable to attach file.')

Comment: i've used this plugin but y usage was for sharing image as meta and text with it but not as files... maybe give it a try to open ur device gmail and try to share the files directly and see if they success. maybe gmail refuses some kind of files like .zip or maybe others and u said files so maybe it could be gmail itself problem or maybe the plugin itself have problem in tis part but first test direct gmail attahcment for ur file (maybe file size also matter)..